# Whats the most elegant way to rearrange an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose you have an associative array

```
$hash['Fruit'] = 'Apple';
$hash['Name'] = 'Jeff';
$hash['Car'] = 'Ford';
```

and you cannot change the order in which these variables are created. So Car is always added to the array after Name, etc. What's the prettiest way to add/move Car to the beginning of the associative array instead of the end (default)?

Comment: are you trying to sort the array?

Comment: and are you trying to sort it by key alphabetically? or do you only want to push car to the top leaving all other elements untouched?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$hash = array('Car' => 'Ford') + $hash;
```

Comment: Hey, great minds *do* think alike :D See my answer for the variable version.

Answer (score 2):

[`ksort()`](http://uk.php.net/ksort) ?

But why would you care about the array's internal order?

Comment: I think he is asking for a push onto the beginning of the array, that's a good hint, though

Comment: I thought about this but figured with his real data this very indirect solution would not always work.

Comment: In this case, I am going to loop over the array with foreach() later, and for display purposes, I want certain values to appear on top.

Answer (score 1):

```
array_reverse($hash, true);
```

This is not a very direct solution but one that is:

```
$value = end($hash);
$hash = array(key($hash) => $value) + $hash;
```

Comment: yep, i've read this ;-) great way to move item that already was added to an array.

Answer (score 0):

Another trick is -

```
$new_items = array('Car' => 'Ford');
$hash = array_merge($new_items, $hash);
```

You can re arrange the new array keys also. Suppose car first then another field (say Id) then array remain so....

```
$new_items = array('Car' => 'Ford','Id'=>'New Id');
$hash = array_merge($new_items, $hash);
```

The array will become like

```
$hash['Car'] = 'Ford';
$hash['Id'] = 'New Id';
$hash['Fruit'] = 'Apple';
$hash['Name'] = 'Jeff';
```